# Apache poi slide show to pdf conversion

Tags: java, pdf, powerpoint, apache-poi

Is there any way to convert generated .**ppt** file using apache poi to .**pdf** file?

```
             OR
```

Any way to convert **PPT** file to **PDF** file using JAVA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use POI to convert [each slide into an image](http://poi.apache.org/slideshow/how-to-shapes.html#Render), then use something like [Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) to place each image onto it's own PDF page. This should work well for simpler PPT files, but the code to render slides is still a WIP. So, if you have a very complex slide, you may find some bits missing/incorrect, do send in patches if you fix any of these gaps!

Otherwise, your other option is to use the Java bindings for OpenOffice, and have that do the conversion for you

Answer (score 7):

Gagravarr, thanks you for your comment with following approach: PPT -> images -> PDF. It gave me clues for further solutions.

Recently, I needed to convert PPT reports into PDF reports using Java facilities. PPT reports are generated via Apache POI lib, and I intended to reuse ready created PPT structure.

I developed two solutions, each has its own advantages/disadvantages. And both of them using iText library with version 2.1.7.(which is free to use, and which is great)). Both of them do support Japanese symbols after additional enhancement.

> **1.** Apache POI Slide -> image -> PDF

Demonstration code example:

```
package com.test.pdf;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.hslf.model.Slide;
import org.apache.poi.hslf.usermodel.SlideShow;

import com.lowagie.text.Document;
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
import com.lowagie.text.Image;
import com.lowagie.text.Rectangle;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class PPTtoImageToPDFexample {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        
        //load any ppt file
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("d:/temp/initialPPT.ppt");
        SlideShow ppt = new SlideShow(inputStream);
        inputStream.close();
        Dimension pgsize = ppt.getPageSize();

        //take first slide and save it as an image
        Slide slide = ppt.getSlides()[0];
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(pgsize.width, pgsize.height,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D graphics = img.createGraphics();
        graphics.setPaint(Color.white);
        graphics.fill(new Rectangle2D.Float(0, 0, pgsize.width,
                pgsize.height));
        slide.draw(graphics);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("d:/temp/slideImage.png");
        javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(img, "png", out);
        out.close();
        
        
        //get saved slide-image and save it into pdf
        Image slideImage = Image.getInstance("d:/temp/slideImage.png");
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("d:/temp/PPTtoImageTest.pdf"));
        document.setPageSize(new Rectangle(slideImage.getWidth(), slideImage.getHeight()));
        document.open();
        slideImage.setAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
        document.add(slideImage);
        document.close();

    }
}
```

> **2.** This approach works on-fly: take Apache POI Slide -> get awt.Graphics2 instance from it -> pass this interface to the iText
> draw engine.

Demonstration code example:

```
package com.test.pdf;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.hslf.model.Slide;
import org.apache.poi.hslf.usermodel.SlideShow;

import com.lowagie.text.Document;
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
import com.lowagie.text.Rectangle;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfGraphics2D;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class PPTtoPDFdirectly {

    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        
        //load any ppt file
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("d:/temp/initialPPT.ppt");
        SlideShow ppt = new SlideShow(inputStream);
        inputStream.close();
        Dimension pgsize = ppt.getPageSize();

        
        //take first slide and draw it directly into PDF via awt.Graphics2D interface.
        Slide slide = ppt.getSlides()[0];
        
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("d:/temp/PPTtoPDF.pdf"));
        document.setPageSize(new Rectangle((float)pgsize.getWidth(), (float) pgsize.getHeight()));
        document.open();
        
        PdfGraphics2D graphics = (PdfGraphics2D) pdfWriter.getDirectContent().createGraphics((float)pgsize.getWidth(), (float)pgsize.getHeight());
        slide.draw(graphics);
        graphics.dispose();
        
        document.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of poi  you are using